# visual studio editor expand collapse widgets are gone

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015

The plus / minus signs are gone to expand / collapse regions. The vertical lines to indicate regions are gone too.

The regions are collapsing and all the commands under edit, outlining work fine.

It's just I have to double click on the collapsed region to expand and there's no way to collapse a region with the mouse. Only the shortcut keys (ctrl m, m) or the menu will do it.

I swear it was right this morning but I did something to mess it up. I can't find any option in tools to fix it either.

**UPDATE**

Now, some files are doing this and other files (both opened at same time) are not doing it. If anyone can explain, I'm all ears.

Comment: You may have stopped the Outlining, Right Click on VS -> Outlining ->Start Automatic Outlining.

Comment: That's probably what I did to break it, but that didn't fix it. It would normally fix it. So it's a partial answer so thanks. As of now I can't reproduce the problem, so I'm still not clear on what makes the glyphs go away when outlining is working. But at least I have a work around.

Comment: I just had this same problem and by the time I finished reading this question my + signs had appeared. It was just really bogged down for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same thing happens to me multiple times a day using VS.NET 2015 Pro version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1. Restarting the IDE always restores normal function for a while but the problem always returns, seemingly at random.

UPDATE:

I tried changing the theme from dark to blue and it restored the outlining. I then changed back to dark from blue and the outlining continued to work normally. Still a pain but definitely a lot faster than restarting the IDE.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is not a perfect or direct solution. Whatever works! Thanks!

Comment: It not working for me. I know this is a old post but I get this issue every so often. I have to close down vs for it to work. That dosent always work either. Is there anything else to try

Answer (score 6):

Press `ctrl+,` (control plus semicolon) to open the `settings`. And type `Folding Strategy` in the setting's search bar. It is set to `auto` by default. You can set it to `always` for the controls to be visible at all times, otherwise, it shows only on mouse over.

Answer (score 2):

It happened with me also. One file was just fine and other file (js) was not. I searched it a lot.

1. Try selecting a method/if check etc and press ctrl+M+H which is short cut for right click outlining > Hide Selection.
   You can do it on the whole document as well. 
   This might be helpful when working on a file which has too much code in it and you are going through different functions again and again. It is painful with scrolling mouse for so long.
2. You can use short cut for for moving at the start of the method or at the end of the method with the following : 
   select parenthesis { start or end } and press ctrl+}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution :

1. two-keystroke sequence : CTRL + M, CTRL + O,
2. then CTRL + Z

Thanks to SparrowEatsHawk

Comment: Ambiguous: You want a two-keystroke sequence Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O; not Ctrl+M, O.  Then undo (Ctrl+Z).  But thanks, this worked!

Comment: Ctrl +M and Ctrl + O will bring the collapse button but it will have all the blocks  collapsed.
To bring back to un-collapsed state press Ctrl+M and Ctrl + L.
To reproduce the scenario where the collapsable buttons are hidden, press Ctrl + M and Ctrl + P

Answer (score 1):

It works again.

I closed all windows and reopened my code file.

Now it shows the plus minus glyphs again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to share a quick solution. if you right click and hover over 'Outlining' and then click 'Collapse to Definition', the widget comes back. Then just press [ctrl] + z to undo and continue where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

With Golang, if the code has some syntactic mistakes that would prevent it from compiling, the language server cannot decide which parts of the code are collapsible, and which not.

Therefore the solution is either switching to the `Folding Strategy` in VSCode settings to `indentation` folding, or fixing the syntactic errors.